# Resting API google setting timeout

Tags: java, android, xml, rest

```
UserActivities response = Resting.getByXML(Urld,Integer.parseInt(tPort), params,UserActivities.class, alias);
```

How can I minimize the time out to  5 seconds? This is being used in production where a lot of hits occur.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to minimize the time-out? I'm guessing you get some ANR (Application Not Responsive) error messages.

N.B.: You shouldn't use this code in the UI thread. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more info.